# nested for loop in need of possible optimisation

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists of users (users1 and users2) and i am comparing them with the following code:

```
def lev(seq1, seq2):
    oneago = None
    thisrow = range(1, len(seq2) + 1) + [0]
    for x in xrange(len(seq1)):
        twoago, oneago, thisrow = oneago, thisrow, [0] * len(seq2) + [x + 1]
        for y in xrange(len(seq2)):
            delcost = oneago[y] + 1
            addcost = thisrow[y - 1] + 1
            subcost = oneago[y - 1] + (seq1[x] != seq2[y])
            thisrow[y] = min(delcost, addcost, subcost)
    return thisrow[len(seq2) - 1]

for x in users1_list:
    for y in users2_list:
        if 3 >= lev(x,y) > 1:
            print x, "seems a lot like", y
```

Can i use list-comprehension to improve the nested for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a list comprehension to improve the nested for loop?

In the `lev` function, I don't think so--at least not in the sense of "this is bad, and a list comprehension is the natural and direct thing that would clean it up."

Yes, you could use a list comprehension there, but several factors argue against comprehensions:

1. You're calculating a lot of things. This means there are many characters required for the resulting expressions (or subexpressions). It would be a very long comprehension expression, making quality formatting difficult and making it harder to hold all of the pieces in your head all at once.
2. You've nicely named the sub-expression components in ways that make logical sense. Spread out into multiple statements, the code is clear about how the deletion, addition, and substation costs are calculated. That's nice. It aids comprehension, esp. for you or someone else who comes back to this code after some time, and has to understand it all over again. If you shorten into a long expression to make a list comprehension neat, you'd remove the clarity of those subexpressions.
3. You do a lot of indexing. That is usually an anti-pattern / bad practice in Python, which has good "iterate over loop items" features. But there are algorithms--and this seems to be one of them--where indexing is the clear method of access. It's very consistent with what you will find in similar programs from other sources, or in reference materials. So using a more primitive indexing approach--something that often doesn't make sense in many Python contexts--works pretty well here.
4. In the second section, where you can loop over items not indices neatly, you do so. It's not like you're trying to avoid Pythonic constructs.

It does jump out at me that you're recalculating `len(seq2)` all the time, even though it seems to be a constant during this function. I'd calculate it once and reuse a stored value. And do you ever really use `twoago`? I didn't see it. So a revised snippet might be:

```
def lev(seq1, seq2):
    oneago = None
    len2 = len(seq2)
    thisrow = range(1, len2 + 1) + [0]
    for x in xrange(len(seq1)):
        oneago, thisrow = thisrow, [0] * len2 + [x + 1]
        for y in xrange(len2):
            delcost = oneago[y] + 1
            addcost = thisrow[y - 1] + 1
            subcost = oneago[y - 1] + (seq1[x] != seq2[y])
            thisrow[y] = min(delcost, addcost, subcost)
    return thisrow[len2 - 1]
```

Finally, stackoverflow tends to be problem related. It has a sister site [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) that might be more appropriate for detailed code improvement suggestions (much as [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is better for more theoretical programming questions).

Comment: thats really helpful thanks for your comments. Didn't know about [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - will bare it in mind next time!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list1 = ['Bret', 'Jermaine', 'Murray']
>>> list2 = ['Jermaine', 'Murray', 'Mel']
```

If the entries in the lists are unique, it might make sense to convert them into sets. You could then see which things are common:

```
>>> set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
{'Jermaine', 'Murray'}
```

The union of both sets can be returned:

```
>>> set(list1).union(set(list2))
{'Bret', 'Jermaine', 'Mel', 'Murray'}
```

To measure the commonality between the two sets, you could calculate the Jaccard index (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index for more details):

```
>>> len(set(list1).intersection(set(list2))) / float(len(set(list1).union(set(list2))))
0.5
```

This the number of common elements divided by the total number of elements.

Comment: thank you, then entries are not unique but you couldn't have known that without me providing more information. Interesting article too!